# Updating multiple input fields onchange in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, onchange, eventhandler

I really hope that you guys can help me with this.
Basically, I am creating an invoice form where users can add multiple items. I have 4 fields for those items: ItemName, ItemPrice (unit price), ItemQuantity and ItemCost (total cost of that item depending on quantity).
The only issue I currently have is that everytime i add a new item, the ItemCost of the previous one shows up. I reckon this comes from my onchange event however I am lost and don't know how to fix it.
Also, note that whereas the first three items are inputs, the last one which is ItemCost is actually a p tag considering that it holds the value of the total cost which should not be editable since it is automatically calculated based on item unit price and quantity.

this is my code:

```
const [ItemName, setItemName] = useState("")
const [ItemPrice, setItemPrice] = useState("")
const [ItemQuantity, setItemQuantity] = useState("")
const [ItemCost, setItemCost] = useState("")
/* END OF DECLARING FORM FIELDS VALUES */

/* HANDLING DYNAMIC ITEMS FIELD */
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    { item_name: '', item_price: '', item_quantity: '', item_cost: '', },
]);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("InputFields", inputFields);
};

const handleAdd = () => {
    setInputFields([...inputFields, { item_name: '', item_price: '', item_quantity: '', item_cost: '', }])
}

const handleRemove = (index) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    values.splice(index, 1);
    setInputFields(values);
}
```

MY INPUT FIELDS

```
                    {inputFields.map((inputField, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className="item_container">
                            <div className='item_fields'>
                                <input
                                    name="item_name"
                                    value={inputField.ItemName}
                                    onChange={(e) => setItemName(e.target.value)}
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Item Name"
                                />

                                <input
                                    name="item_price"
                                    value={inputField.ItemPrice}
                                    onChange={(e) => setItemPrice(e.target.value)}
                                    type="number"
                                    placeholder="Item Price"
                                />

                                <input
                                    name="item_quantity"
                                    value={inputField.ItemQuantity}
                                    onChange={(e) => setItemQuantity(e.target.value)}
                                    type="number" id=""
                                    placeholder="Quantity"
                                />

                                <p
                                    name="item_cost"
                                    value={inputField.ItemCost}
                                    onChange={(e) => setItemCost(e.target.value)}>
                                    {ItemCost}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="buttons">
                                <button disabled={inputFields.length === 1} onClick={() => handleRemove(index)} className='remove_btn' >Remove</button>
                                <button onClick={() => handleAdd()}>Add an item</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
```

[the item fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9nMZ.png)
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkFQX.png)

Comment: Please put the relevant code into the question as text, not an image

Comment: for sure. i'll do that right now

Comment: We may need to also see the structure of the items in `inputFields`? As well as what happens inside `handleAdd()`

Comment: i will update my question accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you write a wrong code, when update any field of an item, you need update right object in item array, use index is easiest way

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function ItemList() {
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    { 
      item_name: '', 
      item_price: '', 
      item_quantity: '', 
      item_cost: '', 
    },
  ]);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("InputFields", inputFields);
};

const handleAdd = () => {
    const newInputFields = [...inputFields];
    newInputFields.push({ 
      item_name: '', 
      item_price: '', 
      item_quantity: '', 
      item_cost: '', 
    });
    setInputFields(newInputFields);
}

const handleRemove = (index) => {
    const newInputFields = [...inputFields];
    newInputFields.splice(index, 1);
    setInputFields(newInputFields);
}

const onItemNameChange = (value, index) => {
  const newInputFields = [...inputFields];
  newInputFields[index].item_name = value;
  setInputFields(newInputFields);
}
const onItemPriceChange = (value, index) => {
  const newInputFields = [...inputFields];
  newInputFields[index].item_price = value;
  newInputFields[index].item_cost = 
    (parseInt(newInputFields[index].item_price, 10) || 0) * 
    (parseInt(newInputFields[index].item_quantity, 10) || 0);
  setInputFields(newInputFields);
}
const onItemQuantityChange = (value, index) => {
  const newInputFields = [...inputFields];
  newInputFields[index].item_quantity = value;
  newInputFields[index].item_cost = 
    parseInt(newInputFields[index].item_price, 10) * 
    parseInt(newInputFields[index].item_quantity, 10);
  setInputFields(newInputFields);
}

  return (
  <>
    {inputFields.map((inputField, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
          <div>
              <input
                  name="item_name"
                  value={inputField.ItemName}
                  onChange={(e) => onItemNameChange(e.target.value, index)}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Item Name"
              />

              <input
                  name="item_price"
                  value={inputField.ItemPrice}
                  onChange={(e) => onItemPriceChange(e.target.value, index)}
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Item Price"
              />

              <input
                  name="item_quantity"
                  value={inputField.ItemQuantity}
                  onChange={(e) => onItemQuantityChange(e.target.value, index)}
                  type="number" id=""
                  placeholder="Quantity"
              />

              <p name="item_cost">
                  total: {inputField.item_cost || 0}
              </p>
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
              <button 
                  disabled={inputFields.length === 1} 
                  onClick={() => handleRemove(index)} 
                  className='remove_btn' 
              >
                Remove
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => handleAdd()}>
                Add an item
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hiep Tran! I tried this and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try-out this solution.
I will give video tutorial for this problem within one week on youtube.
you can watch it from "Debit Code" youtube channel.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-3yWzJVkRD8Jr5gzpupmog?sub_confirmation=1
So, Subscribe the channel, like/comment to the videos, & learn so many things.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Form() {

    // State
    const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([{
        item_name: '',
        item_price: 0,
        item_quantity: 0,
        item_cost: 0,
    }]);

    const setItemName = (value, index) => {
        // const tempList = [...inputFields]
        inputFields[index].item_name = value;
        setInputFields([...inputFields])
    }
    const setItemPrice = (value, index) => {
        // const tempList = [...inputFields]
        inputFields[index].item_price = value;
        setCost(index, value, inputFields[index].item_quantity)
        setInputFields([...inputFields])
    }
    const setItemQuantity = (value, index) => {
        // const tempList = [...inputFields]
        inputFields[index].item_quantity = value;
        setCost(index, inputFields[index].item_price, value)
        setInputFields([...inputFields])
    }

    const setCost = (index, price, quantity) => {
        inputFields[index].item_cost = price * quantity;
        setInputFields([...inputFields])
    }

    const handleRemove = (e, index) => {
        inputFields.splice(index, 1);
        setInputFields([...inputFields]);
    }

    const handleAdd = (e) => {
        var list = [...inputFields];
        list.push({
            item_name: '',
            item_price: '',
            item_quantity: '',
            item_cost: '',
        })
        setInputFields(list)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {inputFields.map((field, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="item_container">
                    <div className='item_fields'>
                        <input
                            name="item_name"
                            value={field.item_name}
                            onChange={(e) => setItemName(e.target.value, index)}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Item Name"
                        />

                        <input
                            name="item_price"
                            value={field.item_price}
                            onChange={(e) => setItemPrice(e.target.value, index)}
                            type="number"
                            placeholder="Item Price"
                        />

                        <input
                            name="item_quantity"
                            value={field.item_quantity}
                            onChange={(e) => setItemQuantity(e.target.value, index)}
                            type="number" id=""
                            placeholder="Quantity"
                        />

                        <p name="item_cost">
                            {field.item_cost}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="buttons">
                        <button disabled={inputFields.length === 1} onClick={(e) => handleRemove(e, index)} className='remove_btn' >Remove</button>
                        <button onClick={() => handleAdd()}>Add an item</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Hello Avishka. Thank you very much for your contribution. Just checked your channel. Keep up the good work!